# Payflow Pro SDK - Authorized Transaction using OrigID

Tags: paypal, payflowpro

I need to create an Authorized transaction but instead of using the credit card number I need to use the OrigID which was generated from a previous payment? Is this possible if so how would I achieve this?

1. Customer places and order -> Authorization is done using the credit card number
2. Order is shipped and invoiced -> Payment is captured using a reference transaction.
3. Same customer places another order -> instead of having to get the credit card details - use the "token" generated from the first transaction (while it is still valid).

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the transaction id that is generated from the first transaction to process additional transactions for the buyer without having to have the buyer enter in their credit card information again.  You would need to enable reference transactions on your account, and store the transaction id's on system.  Then when you want to charge a buyer again, you would just pass over the transaction id of the previous transaction instead of the credit card information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I am already doing this for a normal "Sale" transaction but would like to know how to do an AuthorizationTransaction using the TransactionID. 
Something like AuthorizationTransaction Trans = new AuthorizationTransaction(user_info, payflow_connection, invoice, card_tender, PayflowUtility.RequestId); 
But using the transaction id instead for the CardTender

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand what you are trying to do.  Are you wanting to process a new transactions as an authorization without having to get the buyers details again?  If this is the case, you would still do a reference transaction and just set it to be an authorization rather than a sale.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I needed. ReferenceTransaction Trans = new ReferenceTransaction("A"....)